# Excel in Python - Narrowing Rows Based on Column Values

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Very new to Python so bear with me.

I am looking to filter down an Excel spreadsheet using Python and provided an example below to help explain. For context, I used Pandas to pull in the file.

I have listed two columns: materials and what those materials are used to make. Essentially I want to boil down the spreadsheet to only see materials that are used to make both House and Car (i.e. not one or the other).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! In the future, please provide sample input data, your desired output, and any code attempts you have made.

Here is a way you can achieve your goal, if I understand correctly.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'material': ['wood', 'metal', 'metal', 'glass', 'glass', 'tyres'],
        'uses': ['house', 'house', 'car', 'house', 'car', 'car']
    }
)
```

Our dataset:

```
  material   uses
0     wood  house
1    metal  house
2    metal    car
3    glass  house
4    glass    car
5    tyres    car
```

Then:

```
data.groupby('material').agg(', '.join)[(grouped['uses'].str.contains('house')) & (grouped['uses'].str.contains('car'))]
```

First we group by `material`, and create a string with all the items that were made using that material. This creates a dataframe. Then we can apply two boolean conditions testing for the presence of `house` and `car` in the constructed string.

Result:

```
material        uses  
glass     house, car
metal     house, car
```